# JaxB Xpath : How to use multiple xpath to a same java bean?

Tags: jaxb, for-xml-path

I need to generate xml using jaxb as below :

```
<item>
    <key1 id="default">value1</key1>
    <key2 id="default">value2</key2>
    <key3 id="default">value3</key3>
</item>
```

how to do this using @XmlPath in jaxb?

i have used below one. But i have multiple keys around 50. how to acheive this?

```
   @XmlPath("key1/@id")
    private String attrValue = "default";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@XmlPath` is an extension in the [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation of [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222).  You will need to use the equivalent in MOXy's mapping file to get the desired behaviour.

**oxm.xml**

What you are looking for is the ability to apply multiple writeable mappings for a field/property.  This can't currently be done via annotations, but can be done using MOXy's external mapping document.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum12704491">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Item">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="attrValue" xml-path="key1/@id"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="attrValue" xml-path="key2/@id" write-only="true"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="attrValue" xml-path="key3/@id" write-only="true"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Item**

```java
package forum12704491;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    private String attrValue;
    private String key1;
    private String key2;
    private String key3;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

In order to specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html)

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

The demo code below demonstrates how to bootstrap using MOXy's external mapping document.

```java
package forum12704491;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum12704491/oxm.xml");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Item.class}, properties);

        File xml = new File("src/forum12704491/input.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Item item = (Item) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(item, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
   <key1 id="default">value1</key1>
   <key2 id="default">value2</key2>
   <key3 id="default">value3</key3>
</item>
```

Comment: I know the above answer. Is this possible?
@XmlPath("key1/@id"),@XmlPath("key2/@id"),@XmlPath("key3@id")
    private String attrValue = "default";

Comment: Any news whether and when this feature will be available as an annotation? Thanks